# Trouble understanding my heating system

Tags: water-heater, radiator

[image: pipes in the house]

Hi, just moved to this new place and I'm struggling getting the right temperature for hot water and heater.

Could anyone help me understand the direction and source of each pipe? I guessed some of them, might be wrong.

Also this house has radiator with a fan. Now I can fell the radiator is warm even it was not running. The thermostat is set to 60F but the room is now 78F. What should I adjust(mixing valve?).

Thanks,

Comment: feel the temperature of the pipes

Comment: I'm no pro, but generally circulation pumps **push** water through the radiators, so you may have your arrows backwards. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: do you have thermostats on the radiators?   Generally heat sources have a higher temperature than the room is calling for and are then turned off once the room reaches temperature.  It will take a while for your radiator to cool even if the room is not calling for heat.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger thermostat isset to a much lower temp. And it’s still heating the room slowly after > 12 hours.

Comment: A and B are manifolds.  One is the return and one is the supply.  The supply will be hot and the direction of water flows into the hot one.

Answer (score 0):

On systems I've looked at their are zone valves on the output legs of the manifold which turn on and off with the thermostat.  If the zone is closed and the pump is running no water runs through, generally these are what breaks and it sounds like yours if broken open.  This could also be at the heater, if there is a valve at the heater and it is broken open it will allow water to continue to flow otherwise you'd expect the heater to cool off.

I don't think adjusting the mixing valve is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Here’s my new guess, the direction of the circulating pump should be going up. It pushes hot water to B and returned to A. C is cold water supply. D returns to water heater. E is hot water for the house. F comes directly from water heater. The circulating pump is controlled by thermostats of heat radiator, it runs  by any thermostat when it’s set to on or timer when the time is set to on.